# Application force close when the app is paused one or more hour

Tags: android

I have an order taking screen which has 4000 + Line of code.When i pause the application from this particular activity, i am getting force close due to null pointer exception.I identified couple of objects nullified, which is used in the TextView onClick listener, when i restart the application.I did the following code in the onPause() and onRestart() as follows.But still getting same force close.

```
enter code here


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pause started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ViewConstants.timeOfPause = 0;
        ViewConstants.timeOfPause = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        long applicationIdleTime = Math.abs(ViewConstants.timeOfPause - System.currentTimeMillis());
        if (applicationIdleTime >= 5000) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "restart >5 second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            clearFields();
            ViewConstants.PRODUCT_FIRST_LOAD = true;
            ViewConstants.CATEGORY_FIRST_LOAD = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewOrderActivity.this, NewOrderActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        } else if (stockOrderPreference == null ||
                MBQOrderPreference == null ||
                priceOrderPreference == null ||
                quantityOrderPreference == null ||
                firstDiscountOrderPreference == null ||
                secondlDiscountOrderPreference == null ||
                actualStockOrderPreference == null ||
                perlitreSchemePreference == null ||
                freeQtyPreference == null ||
                salesPromotionPreference == null ||
                decimalOrderQuantity == null ||
                orderBlockWithStock == null ||
                mobileschemePreference == null ||
                mapOrderPreference == null ||
                taxOrderPreference == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "restart due to null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            clearFields();
            ViewConstants.PRODUCT_FIRST_LOAD = true;
            ViewConstants.CATEGORY_FIRST_LOAD = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewOrderActivity.this, NewOrderActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

Comment: can you post logcat trace?

Comment: A typical cause is failure to implement the activity life cycle correctly or to use static variables to store data.

Comment: I think in this case a copy of the entire class would be better. it would show issues tied to @Henry's comment

Comment: If you are using Fragments then http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html  should help to know how to handle application state

Comment: Use good [crash report tool](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/21?sort=rating) to detect the exceptions.

Comment: I got the line in which the exception happened.As a solution what i did is,in the onPause() i will store that time in the variable and in the onRestart(),check the pause time is>some threshold time,load the same screen as fresh.(starting same activity).But still getting null pointerexception

Comment: i am using injection using google guice

Comment: @Henry:can you elaborate little more.